# request focus not working properly

Tags: android, request, focus

I simply have a form inside a layout.I just want to display the top left part(i.e starting field of the form when the form is clicked .I used request focus .However its not working.When i open the form the middle part of the form gets into view and only on scrolling to top I can get the first field.How can I fix this so I can get to the starting part of the form when form is open.This is my form layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.user.educationhunt.UniversityRegistration">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="22dp"
            android:paddingLeft="22dp"
            android:paddingRight="22dp"
            android:paddingTop="22dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:text="Name:">
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/register_school_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:padding="11dp"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:hint="School Name*"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </EditText>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:text="Address:"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/register_school_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:padding="11dp"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:hint="School Address*"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/register_school_district"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/register_school_country"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:text="Phone:"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/register_school_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:padding="11dp"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:hint="School Phone no*"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:text="Email:"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/register_school_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:padding="11dp"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Valid email address*"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:text="Website:"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/register_school_website"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:padding="11dp"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:hint="School Website*"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:text="Institution Type:"/>
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/register_school_institution"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text="Establishment Date:"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/register_school_estdate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:padding="11dp"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:hint="School establishment date*"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:text="Fee Structure:"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/addSchoolProgram"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/register_school_level"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/register_school_annualFee"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                        android:padding="11dp"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:hint="Total Annual fee(NRs)*"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/addSchoolProgram1"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:background="#6c8487"/>
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/register_school_level1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:background="#6c8487"/>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/register_school_annualFee1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                        android:padding="11dp"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:hint="1Total Annual fee(NRs)*"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/addSchoolProgram2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:background="#6c8487"/>
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/register_school_level2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:background="#6c8487"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/register_school_annualFee2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                        android:padding="11dp"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:hint="2Total Annual fee(NRs)*"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/addSchoolProgram3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:background="#6c8487"/>
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/register_school_level3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:background="#6c8487"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/register_school_annualFee3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                        android:padding="11dp"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:hint="3Total Annual fee(NRs)*"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/addSchoolProgram4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:background="#6c8487"/>
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/register_school_level4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:background="#6c8487"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/register_school_annualFee4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                        android:padding="11dp"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:hint="4Total Annual fee(NRs)*"/>

                </LinearLayout>
             </LinearLayout>
               <LinearLayout
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/addSchoolProgram5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:background="#6c8487"/>
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/register_school_level5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:background="#6c8487"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/register_school_annualFee5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                        android:padding="11dp"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:hint="5Total Annual fee(NRs)*"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/addSchoolProgram6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:background="#6c8487"/>
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/register_school_level6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:background="#6c8487"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/register_school_annualFee6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                        android:padding="11dp"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:hint="6Total Annual fee(NRs)*"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/addSchoolProgram7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                        android:background="#6c8487"/>

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/register_school_level7"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>  
    </ScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try requesting focus on the first EditText of the form that is the one with the id register_school_name.

Comment: Bro I tried that already.Its not working

Comment: If you are using this layout in setContentView() of activity the first EditText should automatically get the focus.However to be sure set the ScrollView android:focusable = "true" and android:focusableInTouchMode="true" and try requesting focus for the first editText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
     Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             //focus the view
             edittext.requestFocus();
        });
```

Comment: @therameshbista You can use this code block basicly when form is openning. For example You can override the onStart() method which is one of the lifecycle of Activity. If you want that when user click the form it should be focused, then you can listen the touch event for the scrollview and in there you can also use above code block.